# Find the Maclaurin series of the function

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin series of the function:
$f(x) = \int ^x_0 \frac{sin(t)}{t} dt$

Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this one? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you know how to integrate a power series term by term?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the Maclaurin series of a function $f$ is 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n,
$$
and specifically 
$$
\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
$$
So we have
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_0^x \frac{\sin t}t\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^x t^{2k}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)(2k+1)!},
\end{align}
where the interchange in summation and integration is justified by Fubini's theorem.